# Can the Vacuum Hopper pull items out of Nuka World's Tribute Chest?

Tags: fallout-4

The chest has to be activated before it can be looted by the player, so I was wondering if the Hopper instead of the player can loot the items inside.

I can't test it as I did not unlock the chest yet.